# Need explanation: getText() throws error on getActitvity()ut not on view

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I am a beginner in android development and would appreciate an explanation of the below,

I am trying to get the user input in a custom dialog. The code below works. But if I replace

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

with

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

i get nullPointerException at getText() statement in setPositiveButton().

In addition, any explanation of why i don't get error while declaring but while reading the text (getText()) would be appreciated.

```
public class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_menu, null);

    final EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    builder.setView(view)
            .setMessage("Fire food missile?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), editText.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
             })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Why not?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i get nullPointerException at getText() statement in
>   setPositiveButton().
>
> In addition, any explanation of why i don't get error while declaring
>   but while reading the text (getText()) would be appreciated

`findViewById` is returning null in the second case, because the widget you are looking for, the `TextView`, belongs to the layout you inflated and set as view for the Dialog and not to the `Activity`'s one. Since the returned reference is null, when you try to access one of its members, `getText()` in this case, a `NullPointerException` is thrown